# Connect to gce instance and run command

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, paramiko

I have a simple request. I want to connect to an already existing google compute engine instance, run a command, and close the connection.

I have used the great sample code [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/compute/api/create_instance.py) for instance creation and deletion.

Additionally, I have a startup script running which works perfectly.

Now I am reading [this article](http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different/) to use paramiko to connect to my instance. This may or may not be the best thing to do, so please correct me if I am going down the wrong path.

I have the following sample code:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(
    paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('35.***.***.**',username='user',password='pass')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo su -")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("ls -l")
stdout.readlines()
```

Now - I am not sure which username or password I am supposed to use.

When I run this code, I do not get the list of files and directories in my root as I want, but I do get a list of files and directories in the default user account's `home` - so it is connecting.

My goal is to connect to a gce instance, run a command, and that is it! For some reason it is trickier than I anticipated. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: any reason you're not doing this from the shell? I am not familiar with GCE but I know with AWS when you hop on a new box the root directory has to be accessed by going `cd ../../` to access the root files.

Comment: This should run command as root: `sudo -S -i -u root -p '' pwd`

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy Is my answer what you had in mind?

Comment: for those of you like me who were wondering why sudo su is not persisted to next exec_command, it is because environment variables are not persisted between exec_commands in paramiko. you would need to (if you want to run multiple commands) use invoke_shell or get_pty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are facing a similar use case you can explore [gcloud ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh). It worked for me, but I cannot comment if this is best practice or not.

My solution here was something like the following:

```
import subprocess
def check_for_completion(instance_name = ""):
    cmd = "gcloud compute ssh  %s --zone=us-east1-b --command=\"sudo -S -i -u root -p '' ls /root/temp/ \""%(instance_name)
    try:
        res = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
        items = str(res).split('\n')

        return {'response':items,'complete':False}
    except:
        return {'response':None,'complete':True}
```